# If element has class replace elements 'text' with 'some text'

Tags: jquery

I have a label element:

```
<form id="new_user">
<div id="first-name">
<label for="user_profile_attributes_first_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> First name</label>
</div>
</form>
```

I want to replace the text First name with Team name when #new_user has .team-registration. How it`s better to do that?

```
  if $('#new_user').hasClass('team-registration') {
    ....
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just combine both conditions in one selector? As for the actual replacement, [`$.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) accepts functions too (since jQuery 1.4):

```
$("#new_user.team-registration").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace("First name", "Team name");
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/4m4sa/)!

Note: I'm using `html` instead of `text` as it appears that `#new_user` contains other elements. `text` would remove those tags and give you the flat text, whereas `html` acts on the actual `innerHTML`.

Note: `string.replace(string, string)` only replaces the *first occurrence*. If you need to replace *all occurrences*, use a regular expression:

```
    return html.replace(/First name/g, "Team name");
```

Comment: Please, note that i have <abbr title="required">*</abbr> before the text which is to be replaced

Comment: @RooticalV. Do you want to simply replace *all contents* of `#new_user.team-registration` with `"Team name"`? Or do you want it to result in `"<abbr title="required">*</abbr> Team name"`? Also, the HTML snippet in your question doesn't match your required conditions. It'd help if you updated your question to include the correct HTML as well as the expected resulting HTML.

Comment: I`ve edited the html. Yes i want only text to be replaced and <abbr title="required">*</abbr> to leave on its place.
Thanks!

Comment: @RooticalV. Then this will do what you want. `html.replace` will find all occurrences of `"First name"` and replace them with `"Team name"`, keeping all other HTML intact.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
if $('#new_user').hasClass('team-registration') {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('First','Team')
}
```

In the above I've opted only to replace the string 'First`, since the second word ('name') is consistent between both.

I would, of course, note that you've got no element of `id="new_user"` in your provided mark-up, so I'd strongly suggest that you ensure you're using the correct `id` selector, since this approach will replace text within the matching element, it *won't* attempt to search the descendant elements of the matched element for occurrences of the string to be replaced.

References:

- [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).